# variable definition in python

Tags: python, variables

I've been through C++ and am now learning Python.  I am a bit confused on whats going on with variables here.  I 'feel' like I should declare "wt" as Real or Float but it won't accept that syntax.  I think the error is on the line where I declare the module "calcAndDisplayShipping".

The goal of the program is to compute price based on input weight.

```
#main module
def main():

    #local variables
    weight = 0.0

    #get package weight
    weight = input("Enter the weight of your package: ")

    #call module to calculate and display shipping charges
    calcAndDisplayShipping (weight)

#module for calculating and displaying shipping charge
def calcAndDisplayShipping (wt):

    #named constants for rates
    underTwo = 1.10
    twoToSix = 2.20,
    sixToTen = 3.70
    overTen= 3.80

    #Local Variable
    shipping = 0.0

    #calculate charges
    if wt > 10.0:
        shipping = wt * overTen
    elif wt > 6.0:
        shipping = wt * sixToTen
    elif wt > 2.0:
        shipping = wt * twoToSix
    else:
        shipping = wt * underTwo

    #display shipping charge
    print ("Shipping charge for this package is: $", shipping)

    #return to main
    main()
```

The error I get is ...
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

I searched through my language companion for python and couldn't find any help.

Comment: Just type-convert `wt` to a float (`float(wt)`). You'll need some exception handling if the user enters a non-numeric value.

Comment: I think this works in Python2... Python3 gives you a string, even though you seem to think you typed a number

Comment: Also important to note that Python is dynamically typed, unlike C++, so you don't need to declare variable types.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `input` returns a string. To get a float, you should wrap this call in `float()`.

```
weight = input("Enter the weight of your package: ")
```

There's another issue you might run into here that as this is currently written, you never step out of a function call - you only increase the size of your call stack. Instead you probably want to delete the call to `main` at the end of `calcAndDisplayShipping`, and then in `main` use a while loop.

```
def main():

    #local variables
    weight = 0.0

    while True:
        #get package weight
        weight = float(input("Enter the weight of your package: "))

        #call module to calculate and display shipping charges
        calcAndDisplayShipping(weight)
```

Comment: Or `calcAndDisplayShipping (float(weight))`

Comment: I’m pretty sure the OP wanted it to be float not int.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here. The main one is that you don't convert the string to a float before assigning to `weight`. You can do that with:

```
weight = float(input(...
```

You don't need to set `weight = 0.0` before that. It gets completely overwritten.

Other issues are that your indentation is wrong and the "calculate charges" fragment is outside of the function. It would run as part of the module's code block.

Your naming in the comments is also incorrect. You're defining functions, not modules. (`main`, `calcAndDisplayShipping`) Also at the end you're calling `main`, not returning to it.

Finally this doesn't do what you expect:

```
twoToSix = 2.20,
```

It defines a 1-element tuple and is equivalent to `twoToSix = (2.20,)`. You need to remove the comma to get a number itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.x doesn't evaluate and convert the data type, you have to explicitly convert to floats, with float, like this `float(input("question:"))`

Try this:

```
def main():
    weight = 0.0
    weight = float(input("Enter the weight of your package: "))
    #call module to calculate and display shipping charges
    calcAndDisplayShipping (weight)

#module for calculating and displaying shipping charge
def calcAndDisplayShipping (wt):

    #named constants for rates
    underTwo = 1.10
    twoToSix = 2.20,
    sixToTen = 3.70
    overTen= 3.80

    #Local Variable
    shipping = 0.0

    #calculate charges
    if wt > 10.0:
        shipping = wt * overTen
    elif wt > 6.0:
        shipping = wt * sixToTen
    elif wt > 2.0:
        shipping = wt * twoToSix
    else:
        shipping = wt * underTwo
    #display shipping charge
    print ("Shipping charge for this package is: $", shipping)

#return to main
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mainly indentation, in your variable wt must be inside the indentation of your function, and you must cast the input to a float variable like in the code below, I also removed a comma misplaced. And be aware that the main() on the end calls the function main, but doesn't return to anything.

```
#main module
def main():

    #local variables
    weight = 0.0

    #get package weight
    weight = float(input("Enter the weight of your package: "))

    #call module to calculate and display shipping charges
    calcAndDisplayShipping (weight)

#module for calculating and displaying shipping charge
def calcAndDisplayShipping (wt):

    #named constants for rates
    underTwo = 1.10
    twoToSix = 2.20
    sixToTen = 3.70
    overTen = 3.80

    #Local Variable
    shipping = 0.0

    #calculate charges
    if wt > 10.0:
        shipping = wt * overTen
    elif wt > 6.0:
        shipping = wt * sixToTen
    elif wt > 2.0:
        shipping = wt * twoToSix
    else:
        shipping = wt * underTwo


    #display shipping charge
    print ("Shipping charge for this package is: $", shipping)

# calls main function!!!!!
main()
```